# How to see total memory usage per app?

Tags: macos, memory, memory-pressure

Is there a way to see memory usage per app in macOS? 
That is, I want to see the **total** memory consumed by each app, including  its child processes.

The Activity Monitor shows memory usage by process which makes it hard to determine, for example, how much memory the Chrome app is using, since it spawns multiple processes.

Comment: For Chrome specifically have you used its built in task manager?

Comment: Alternatively, don't use Chrome, and your memory management issues will melt away. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Activity Monitor > View > All Processes, Hierarchically ought to do it, with a bit of scrolling...

[image]

Comment: This seemed promising. But on checking I found that the it still doesn't show the *total* memory being used by an App. It's just individual processes grouped under the parent process. (You can verify that for the Safari and Mail apps shown in your screen shot -- the memory usage doesn't add up). In fact, on my Mac currently, the Chrome.app has child processes that individually seem to be using more memory than the parent Chrome.app process.

Comment: Without knowing for certain, I'd say that you would need to add up all the child processes, then add the parent, to get the true total - I think you're assuming the parent IS the total. I would assume it's not. A simple test for that would be to check the kernel task total, which is nowhere near the sum of it's sub-processes.

Comment: That's exactly what I said above... this view doesn't show the total memory usage per app. I am looking for a method that does. I can't be bothered to add 30 3-digit numbers each time I want to see how much memory chrome is using.

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck - they are child processes, subordinate but separate to the main process. My fairly decent  Google-Fu finds no utility that will add them up automatically. Maybe someone else can find one...

Comment: Or maybe create one ;)

Comment: It's not that simple, processes can share memory, so total memory is not as easy as add all memory from the children. Plus, there's virtual versus real memory. It's a slightly complicated beast. :-(

Comment: how do i find the activity monitor??

Comment: Applications/Utilities

Comment: Would love to know this too. Trying to figure out how much RAM Chrome and it's child helpers are using.. no easy task it seems

Comment: This doesn't work. Look at how `kernel_task` doesn't include the memory used by Xcode, so thus child processes of Xcode like the app `Prime Calc` I'm building with it aren't included in Xcode's memory count. See image: http://imgur.com/a/tF72o

Comment: @chmac Windows Task Manager shows the correct sum of memory of used by related processes, such as Chrome or Firefox. So there's no reason macOS couldn't do the same.

Answer (score 6):

If you're not fussed about having a nice GUI and have a python distro installed, you can use [psrecord](https://github.com/astrofrog/psrecord).

- Open Terminal
- Install with `pip install psrecord`
- Get the Chrome PID (can use activity monitor)

[image: Activity Monitor]

- Run psrecord, with the `--include-children` flag, providing the PID as an argument

*I would recommend specifying some duration (60s in my examples) otherwise psrecord would continue running until Chrome is terminated.*

psrecord will record the CPU usage (%) and Memory usage (MB) which you can have it output as either a plot:

```
psrecord 95639 --plot chrome.png --include-children --duration 60
```

[image: psrecord plot]

or a log file:

```
psrecord 95639 --log chrome.txt --include-children --duration 60
```

```
# Elapsed time   CPU (%)     Real (MB)   Virtual (MB)
       0.000        0.000     1672.918    65500.004
       0.078        2.400     1672.922    65500.004
       0.161        3.200     1672.926    65500.004
       0.245        3.400     1672.926    65500.004
       0.329        4.300     1672.930    65500.004
       0.410        3.400     1672.934    65500.004
       0.492        3.900     1672.938    65500.004
       0.580        2.700     1672.941    65500.004
       0.667        3.200     1672.945    65527.895
       0.748        3.100     1672.945    65500.004
       0.830        3.200     1672.949    65500.004
       0.911        3.000     1672.953    65500.004
       0.993        3.200     1672.953    65500.004
       1.074        3.500     1672.957    65500.004
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm totally a fan of [`htop`](https://hisham.hm/htop/index.php) which can be installed via Homebrew, which is more powerful and flexible than the activity monitor.

Run it in a console, I think it's straightforward.

Comment: htop I think has the same problem as Activity Monitor. That is, if you collapse child processes in hierarchical view, it doesn't total up the child processes, it only shows memory of parent process. Unless there's some button I need to push I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 1):

For any one coming here, you can use this script:

```
a=0;for i ($(ps -e -o %mem,command | grep 'Google Chrome' | grep -oE '\d\.\d /Applications' | grep -oE '\d\.\d')) { a=$((a+i)) }; print $a
```

Change `Google Chrome` to your name of app, that will work for app under the `/Application` directory.

Comment: What does this command do? How does it work? What will be an example result? Please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/458648/edit) your answer to add more supporting information and explanations.

Comment: @thinkr It seems to be rather complicated and zsh-specific way of writing `ps -e -o %mem,command | awk '/Google Chrome/ { size += $1 } END { print size}'`. So basically it uses `ps` to get the memory footprint of all processes, filters for Google Chrome and sums up the memory needed by all its processes.

Comment: @nohillside Thank you for explaining it to me but I wanted to advise @ ZHDI on how to write a good answer, comprehensible to all.

Comment: @thinkr I know, your first comment was spot on. Primarily wanted to point out that the same result can be achieved way simpler by just using `awk` to do all the work.

Comment: @nohillside I guess you could post it as an answer then? :)

Comment: @Thinkr It doesn't solve the problem stated in the question ("That is, I want to see the total memory consumed by each app, including its child processes.") as it assumes that all child processes have "Google Chrome" somewhere in their name or path (neither does the solution posted by ZHDI, actually, nor most of the other answers). You can't derive the full memory footprint without looking at the whole process tree.

Comment: @nohillside Agreed :)

Comment: You are right, and i use this script for long time, so I just put in here when i see this thread, i will try to edit it to more generally((

Answer (score 1):

[iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) does provide the memory used for the 5 applications that use the most memory summing up their child processes (although it can also show sepate process values like Activity Monitor).

Answer (score 0):

There is **USS** in MacOS available.

> The USS (Unique Set Size) is the memory which is unique to a process and which would be freed if the process was terminated right now.

[psutil>4.0 Python library can access it](http://www.pybloggers.com/2016/02/psutil-4-0-0-and-how-to-get-real-process-memory-and-environ-in-python/)

Here is I would use it

```
sudo python3 -c "import psutil;print(sum(p.memory_full_info().uss for p in psutil.Process(pid=292).children())/1024/1024);"
```

where pid=292 is PID of most outer process from Activity Monitor.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Mojave. Running with sudo, trying to get the info for a process executing as my uid, I get "psutil.AccessDenied". I'm sure it's some sort of macOS security feature, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Hmm it worked for me on Mojave

Comment: I will also add that my normal account does NOT have admin access. As a security precaution, I have a separate account with admin privileges, and I just enter that admin password when needed. I haven't tried it, but it's possible that it might work if I added admin privileges to my main account.